# Why Node.removeChild(Old Child) doesn't works in functions?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a button when i click it i want to print hello plus the innerHTML of the button and remove itself :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc(element) {
        var parentNd = element.parentElement
        parentNd.innerHTML += "<p>Hello</p>" + element.innerHTML
        parentNd.removeChild(element)
    }
</script>
<button onclick="MyFunc(this);">My Button</button>
```

but it's just print the text and don't remove itself
why?

Comment: good question, definitely new information for someone. so my +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rewriting the parent's innerHTML, you're replacing the button with a copy (since the HTML that defines the button is parsed again). So your reference to `element` points to a button that is no longer in the DOM, therefore removing it has no effect.

I suggest you stop using innerHTML, create the P element with `createElement` and then call `replaceChild` to swap it with the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery

```
<button id="x" onclick="MyFunc(this);">My Button</button>

function MyFunc(element) {
        var parentNd = element.parentElement
        parentNd.innerHTML += "<p>Hello</p>" + element.innerHTML
         $("#x").remove();
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tcm50ovy/)**

OR use below code it will also works

```
function MyFunc(element) {
    var parentNd = element.parentElement
    document.write(element.innerHTML);
   parentNd.removeChild(element);
}
```

Note: I didn't prefer this method , i think the best idea is hide the button in onclick event

Answer (score 0):

this is okey!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc(element) {
        var parentNd = element.parentElement
        parentNd.removeChild(element)
        parentNd.innerHTML += "<p>Hello</p>" + element.innerHTML

    }
</script>
<button onclick="MyFunc(this);">My Button</button>
```